# mod_rewrite regex to match only if a certain string does NOT exist

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

Looking through my server logs, I see that a lot of pages on my site are requesting `favicon.ico`, `favicon.jpg`, `favicon.png`, etc in a variety of different directories.

Instead of wading through each page to try to figure out where each incorrect request is coming from, I'm writing some apache redirect rules to change a request for any url containing `"favicon"` to redirect to `/favicon.ico`

My initial naive attempt was this:

```
RewriteRule favicon /favicon.ico [R=301,L]
```

But that meant that when you actually requested `/favicon.ico` it would send you into an infinite redirect loop.

Basically what I think I need is a regex which has this effect:

```
| Request                | Response     |
|------------------------|--------------|
| favicon.png            | /favicon.ico |
| directory/favicon.png  | /favicon.ico |
| directory/favicon.ico  | /favicon.ico |
| favicon.ico            | <no match>   |
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC] # if not already going to favicon.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.ico [NC] # edit this line to match your favicon matching regex
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com.au/favicon.ico [R=301,L] #redirect to the real address
```

Comment: Look at Dscoduc's response! (More detailed.)

Answer (score 11):

Couple of changes I would suggest to alter [Alex's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/514633/31671):

Keep this section the same:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
```

Check for more than just the .ico extension at the end of the request:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.(ico|png|gif)$ [NC]
```

Add a 3rd condition that grabs the current request host name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)
```

Finally change the last RewriteRule to use a %1 ([a backreference representing the last matched condition](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)):

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/favicon.ico [R=301,L]
```

The final result would look like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} favicon\.(ico|png|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)
RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/favicon.ico [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: Something I did the other day, is to change the extension checker to .(ico|gif|png|jpe?g) for good measure :)

Comment: the rewrite rule should be `RewriteRule (.*) http://%1/favicon.ico [R=301,L]` since the `%1` is a `backreference` - in other words `%1` will give the last matched RewriteRule while `%3` will give the third-last matched RewriteCond (which is this case is the first RewriteCond and may not even have a 'grouped part')  - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
RewriteRule favicon[.](\w*)$ /favicon.ico [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico$
RewriteRule favicon /favicon.ico [L,R=301]
```